# Using MAX and GROUP BY on IQueryable with Navigation Properties

Tags: entity-framework

I need to use MAX and GROUP BY on EntitySQL query with Navigation Properties. I have the below query. I need to select the records with the latest 'CREATED' column which is present in the Navigation Property of the table 'APPROVALS'.

Please help with the query.

```
public IQueryable<TravelRequest> GetTravelRequestswithChildrenForGuid(Guid ID)
{
   IQueryable<TravelRequest> v = this.ObjectContext.TravelRequests
   .Include("CarRentals").Include("CarRentals.CarRentalType")
   .Include("Approvals").Include("Approvals.ApprovalType")
   .Include("Accomodations")
   .Include("TravelRequestStatus").Where(t => t.RowGuid.Equals(ID));    

   foreach (TravelRequest t in v)
   {
      t.Flights.Clear();
      foreach (Flight f in GetFlightsForTravelRequest(t.RowGuid))
      {
         t.Flights.Add(f);
      }
   }

   return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier in this case to use the from-select-where notation. Have a look at the LINQ 101 group by examples:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

I don't know how complex your GetFlightsForTravelRequest method is, but you can easily kill a lot of performance by trying to reuse code in your data layer. One dedicated query is often better. In your code you'll lose the benefit of defered execution by using the for-loop.

My advise would be to think of the SQL query you want to execute and work your way back to LINQ.